# how to break the line in value of input field

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I am trying to put some more data into value part of an input. but I want those strings to have line break.

```
<input type="text" value="text break text"/>
```

I want the value to be shown:

```
text 
text
```

how can I do this? I am trying to add this with template engine of django, but django doesnot have it.

appreciate any help

Comment: You need a textarea. Text input fields do not show linefeeds

Comment: Why would you want an element to be shown in two lines, when it is functionally a control for single-line input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, you need to use `<textarea />` instead of `<input type="text" />` field. To break the lines, just use the normal line break like this:

```
<textarea>
    Line 1
    Line 2
</textarea>
```

You may find more about `<textarea/>` in [HTML 4.01 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#h-17.7).

Comment: okay, what would then be the solution? ``\n`` ?

Comment: @doniyor Yes, the normal line break. I've edited my answer to clarify that.

Comment: ``<br/>`` did the job in textarea.

Comment: @doniyor Hmm... That's strange. `<br/>` didn't work in my tests, while normal `\n` did.

Comment: @Alexey [Please don't link to w3schools.](http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: @michaelb958 Thanks, now I know that. Replacing with a reference to W3C specification.